# php imap function find bounce backs

Tags: php

So I have the basic problem of a mailing list and I am trying to find all the undeliverable emails and turn them off. I am using php imap function and I have been going through all the fetch and structure functions and although they do give you the information is there anything that concisely will say this is a bad email based on the error code. Currently my best option is using imap_fetchbody with option 2 and doing a find for 550 or 5.4.4 or 5.1.1 etc and then grabbing the email. I wanted to know if there was a function that tells you bad good or at least just has the above codes 550, 5.4.4 etc in a concise array format.

```
set_time_limit(0);
$hostname = "{localhost:110/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$username = 'xxxx';
$password = "xxxx";

$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Cannot connect to pop: " .         imap_last_error());
 $emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
if($emails){
$output = '';
rsort($emails);
foreach($emails as $key1 => $email_number){
    if($key1 < 10){
        $imap_fetchstructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);
        $imap_fetchbody = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1);
        $imap_fetch_overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number);
        $imap_bodystruct = imap_bodystruct($inbox, $email_number, 1);`      
    } else{
        break;
    }
}
}
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: The tutorial helped me with this problem: http://cheesefather.com/2011/12/process-email-bounces-with-php/ . It has broken class link which you can find here: https://github.com/cfortune/PHP-Bounce-Handler .